# Getting error while running ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-7, rubygems, stomp

I am trying to run a ruby script which is basically a Stomp client to make call to ActiveMQ broker.

When i run the script, i get this error:

```
going to startC:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
4:in `require': cannot load such file -- stomp (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Users/lokesh.kumar/Documents/issues/ActiveMQ-slowness/activemq-c
acti-plugin.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

Following is the result of command `gem env`

```
C:\Users\lokesh.kumar>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.5 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 319) [x64-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby22-x64/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: Z:/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x64-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - Z:/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin
     - C:\Windows\system32
     - C:\Windows
     - C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
     - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
     - C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\
     - C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
     - c:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin
     - C:\Ruby22-x64\bin
     - C:\Users\lokesh.kumar\.babun
     - D:\Installations\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin
```

I have never worked in Ruby, so it might be a basic installation mistake. Any pointers to resolve this?

Comment: have you installed stomp gem? please show output of `gem which stomp`.

Comment: @Aleksey: It says "ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library stomp". Can you give me the command to install Stomp?

Comment: To install a gem run `gem install GEMNAME`. In this particular case `gem install stomp`

Comment: @Aleksey: Thanks a lot. Finally the issue is resolved. If you can add your comment as answer then i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you don't have `stomp` gem installed.
You can install any gem you want with `gem install GEMNAME`.

In your particular case `GEMNAME` is `stomp`.
So try to run `gem install stomp` and run your script once again.

*P.S.*
By default `gem install` command uses [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/) as gem source.
So you can always check out gem names here.